# Creating / Attaching module in Access database at runtime from VB6 application

Tags: ms-access, vb6, module

Inside Access I can go into Modules and create a new module and put a function inside it.

How can I do this at runtime from a VB6 application?

I have tried CREATE FUNCTION .. CREATE PROCEDURE .. but I may also have an aspect of this is actually an Access 2000 database which maybe does not support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only find code to do this in Access 97 [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;175218)

```
Sub CreateNewModule()

  Dim MyMod As Module
  Dim MyStr As String

  DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdNewObjectModule  ' Create new module.

  MyStr = "Sub Test2()" & vbCrLf         ' Create text for the module.

  MyStr = MyStr & Space$(4) & "MsgBox " & Chr$(34) & "test2" & _
  Chr$(34) & vbCrLf

  MyStr = MyStr & "End Sub"

  Set MyMod = Modules("Module3")         ' Give module a name.

  MyMod.InsertText MyStr                 ' Insert text into the module.

  DoCmd.Close acModule, "Module3", acSaveYes   ' Close and save module.

End Sub
```

In terms of doing this from VB6, you would need to use automation, and then the functions like `DoCmd` and `Modules()` should be available.

For example, something like this (untested) should get you started.

```
Dim oApp As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")

oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\MyDatabase.mdb"

oApp.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdNewObjectModule

...
... (Rest of code to automate Access here)
...

Set oApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks! My apologies for the delay. Programming sidetracks and all :). Works great.